# Test Worker Thread Pool Availability Of App Port In For Health Check

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

Recently I encounter a situation that connections stuck in close_wait state.

Tomcat soon run out of worker threads and stopped accepting requests.

I was not able to locate the exact reason for the trouble as the process was already restarted.

Alternativly, I want to design a health indicator to check the availability of Tomcat worker thread pool.

The actuator runs at another port from the app port.
Thus they use different thread pools.

I wonder if there is solution to check the status of the worker thead pool of the app port from a health indicator.

Thank you if any help.

(Spring Boot 2.2.7)

Comment: If your primary connector is not answering requests, wouldn't you *want* the health-check to fail to connect? The server is _NOT_ healthy in that situation.

Comment: Yes, I want the health-check to fail to connect when the app port is not connectable.

Comment: Then just connect directly to the service port. If you can't connect, the service is down!

Comment: Run actuator on service port is a bit more risky. Using seperated port is for safety concerns.

Comment: Okay, then run the actuator (what is this?) on the other port and have them share the thread pool. Just return 200 without performing any specific checks, since the response is evidence enough that the thread pool is healthy.